# Facebook connect issue

Tags: android, facebook

I have an android app of my own , in that there is a module using which one can post an event on Facebook by entering the start date, time.

This app asks for the Login email Id and Password for the first time. Then it saves the credentials and automatically posts the event next time the user uses this app.

The problem is, I have a scenario where the official Facebook app is there in the android phone.The user is already logged in , in the phone. Then if the user installs my app and uses the Facebook feature then it neither asks for the Login Email and password nor does it posts any event. But works perfectly fine if the Official Facebook app is UN-installed.

Please Help. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you provided a bit more detail about your app - and perhaps some code? But guessing based on what you say...

Is your app using the Facebook SDK authorize method? That uses Single Sign On (SSO) by default, which results in the SDK checking for the presence of the Facebook app, and if it is present, using the login status of the Facebook app. That would explain why you do not see a login when the app is present and the user logged in, and why you do when the app is not present.

You can disable SSO by passing FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH as the activityCode parameter in your call to authorize().

Comment: I have used the "fbconnect" downloaded from https://github.com/facebook/connect-js.

Comment: public static final int FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH = -1;   ----this is the line you are saying about present in Facebook.java file in fbconnect package

Comment: public static final String SINGLE_SIGN_ON_DISABLED = "service_disabled";------this is the line you are saying about present in Facebook.java file in fbconnect package

Comment: I was talking about the Android Facebook SDK (at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/) which has the options I mentioned. If you are writing an Android app you should be using that. You should not be using the Javascript SDK (you link to above) for an Android app - that is solely for a web-based server-side  app.